# Mac beeps when I type end parantheses in commented block of Python

Tags: python, macos, comments, python-idle, beep

Why, when I type an end parantheses in a commented out area in IDLE, does mac sound the error beep, and how can I stop it?

Comment: I gave a general answer below.  However, your description is too vague to try to reproduce your actions., and be more specific.  If you edit to give an exact example of actions that lead to a beep, I will try to improve the answer.

Comment: for example when I type
`code`
#blahblah...)
`code`
right when i hit the end parantheses, even if there's an opening parantheses to match, my mac will sound beep

Comment: That seems pretty idiosyncratic to Mac or your particular system.  I have no idea what could make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various programs, including IDLE, sometimes ask the computer to 'beep' when the user does something that the program considers an error.  In general, to not hear a beep, you can 1) stop doing whatever provokes the beep, 2) turn your speaker down or off, or 3) plug in earphones and not wear them while editing.